# Sharing svn reposities between web servers

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, load-balancing

I have my subversion hosting set up to be accessed through Apache web server. Everything runs fine. Now I'd like to add another web server to distribute the load between two web servers.

Is it save to have my svn repositories accessed by two web servers at the same time? Does the normal fsfs subversion repository type protect me enough or do I need to switch to Berkely DB for this sort of thing?

Comment: How is your SVN repo going to be shared between the webservers?  NFS, GFS, OCFS, <insert nightmare of choice here>

Comment: I was thinking of NFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subversion repositories are happy to be accessed by multiple users at the same time. It will do the correct locking. Adding an additional apache accessing it will not cause any problem with any backend. I really advise against using the Berkeley DB backend. It causes no end of pain.

The problem you will have to solve is how to share the repository between both servers. If one server is still hosting the files, it's still going to get the same amount of IO load, although the amount of CPU usage will be reduced. You will also need to deal with keeping the configuration in sync between servers.

Comment: Thanks for that! I was think of setting up and NFS file server where both web servers will talk to. I need to do some test though. My question was actually a bit stupid I realized later because if multiple processes (Apache) can access the repos at the same time than it should be OK to have processes from different servers do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe.